# Grails - Scaffolding plugin doesn't make date required

Tags: grails, properties, scaffolding, required

I wanted to customize the `renderEditor.template`. However, I noticed that `Date` properties of my domain class are never `required`. No matter, if they are set `nullable: true` or `nullable: false`.

I extended the `renderFieldForProperty` method in the `_form.gsp` of the scaffolding plugin as follows to check the `nullable` property:

```
if (hasHibernate) {
    cp = owningClass.constrainedProperties[p.name]
    required = (cp ? !(cp.propertyType in [boolean, Boolean]) && !cp.nullable : false)
    // added line:
    println p.name + " " + cp.nullable + " ... " + required
}
```

However, for `Date` properties I always get the following output:

`dateField true ... false`

For a `String` property which has not been set `nullable: true` I get:

`stringProperty false ... true`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would help if you posted your example domain class. Based on your output `dateField true ... false` the nullable constraint is still set to true, which would make the field not required.

Comment: Apparently a clean/build of the project has resolved the problem, now the fields are set required as intended. Thank you for your help, I'm sorry to have bothered you.